# Stop progress bar's rotation

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm trying to use rotating progress bar in Android, but there's a problem about rotation. It never stops. I tried `clearAnimation()` but it doesn't work. I've searched on the internet and mainly suggestions were about changing progress bar's visibility like `progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`. But is there a way to actually stop progress bar's rotation without hiding it? My code looks like this.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.animate();
        }

        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
                //doing some stuff
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document result) 
        {   
                progressBar.clearAnimation();//doesn't help
                //doing some stuff
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(Document result) {
            super.onCancelled(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }       
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that's possible, sorry.

you would have to replace the progressBar with an image representation. so hide the progressbar and show the image...